# Staff/employee shift scheduling

Tags: webapp-rec

We have over 100 part-time staff currently. I would like to know if there's a solution (hosted or self-hosted) that would allow us to put work schedules together easily. Perhaps it could even email notices to the staff notifying them of their upcoming week's schedule. So far I've found:

`findmyshift.com`, `fendza.com` and `shiftplanning.com`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself but [EZShift](http://www.ezshift.com/) looks promising, since they have pretty big [customers](http://www.ezshift.com/Default.aspx?PageID=12).

They also have a cool challenge (plus the first month is for Free, so you have nothing to lose):

> EZShift believes that our employee scheduling software can implement 
>   all specific needs of your company's shift schedule. Along with our automatic shift scheduling, you will be able to set the optimal shift for all employees according to your employee scheduling needs. 
>   The software will also eliminate any possible mistakes and shift scheduling conflicts. If you can come up with a single organizational need that our rule engine can not solve – 
>   **you will receive 3 months for free!**

Answer (score 0):

We've been using [Findmyshift](http://www.findmyshift.com/) for the past 8 months for our call centre staff. We've got just over 200 staff using it and never had a problem. We've split our account in to different departments, but there's no limit as to how many staff you can have in each. For price, flexibility and ease of use it was the clear winner for us. I think it's free for the first month too.

Answer (score 0):

/sideeye/ to the previous two "testimonial" comments.. lol

My name is James and I am the founder for Fendza. We're still in private beta, which is probably why you haven't ran across too many reviews on us yet. Although; we've been mentioned in a few pretty reputable sources.

Anyways, our employee scheduling software will be pretty darn good. Ours does one thing very, very well which is automatically making work schedules for you that fit everybody's availability, business hours, needed positions and departments per shift, approved requests, etc. etc. Most of the other employee scheduling software out there doesn't do this; you basically have to click each shift on each person on each day and enter in your info. You may as well just do it by pen and paper; because it's the equivalent of spending the same amount of time and thought doing it on the web app.

We really took a look at the market, what was missing, and thought everything well through, hence there will be a huge difference in quality, design, and ease of use with ours. All the small things that matter.

Anyways, feel free to try out our live demo on the site at: [Fendza.com](http://www.fendza.com) If you're interested in being a tester for us (same offer goes out to everyone else here at stackexchange), we'll hook you up with a free account.

Answer (score 0):

We've been using ShiftPlanning's [employee scheduling software](http://www.shiftplanning.com) with our Google Apps account and love it. It's the only solution that we found that was both intuitive and adaptable to our business. We tried out the 30-day trial after reading the reviews in the Google Apps MarketPlace -

www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/viewListing?productListingId=5951+15332219965537647988

Good luck finding a product that works for your business!

Comment: Shiftplanning has a great set of features upon review. Unfortunately, it costs more than we can budget. We are a seasonal business and during our peak months, we peak with over 100 employees; this would could over $100 per month just for scheduling software. That's the tough part - balancing costs with functionality.

Answer (score 0):

My name is Shay and I am one of the founders of Otipo. 
Otipo is an [employee scheduling software](http://otipo.com) that is easy to use and a very affordable solution. You can try it out for free, and see that it fits your needs. It is in use by many help desks and call centers, restaurants, EMS call centers, and other businesses. 
With the predefined templates, you can setup your business in minutes, and then start getting your employee's availability online, create a schedule automatically, remind employees before shifts and basically reduce 90% of the manual work related to scheduling.

If you need any more info or assistance feel free to [contact us](http://otipo.com/contact/).

And please share with the forum what you have found to be most useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

The best option for scheduling your staff can be [eResource scheduler](https://www.eresourcescheduler.com) by Enbraun Corp. Our Company is using the software for quite a long time,it can send E-mail to the employees notifying them about their upcoming schedule.Facilitate drag ans drop scheduling, graphic rich reports, time sheets, etc.You can take trial or 14 long days.

Comment: Can you tell me more about eresource scheduler ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest [When I Work](http://wheniwork.com). It's very straightforward, easy-to-use and there are free iPhone and Android apps that work with it.

Full disclaimer: I am the founder of When I Work, but if you want to look for some other options, I'd suggest http://alternativeto.net/ and searching for "employee scheduling". Lots of option there.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for a self-hosted solution, I'd suggest to have a look at [ShiftExec](http://www.shiftexec.com) with a clean and simple design.

Comment: Are you affiliated with ShiftExec? If so, you should disclose it.

Comment: yes, sorry I didn't disclose it right away, sorry. We've developed ShiftExec.

Answer (score 0):

We switched our staff management system to E Works Manager 6 months ago, and now all of our documentation and procedures are carried out completely online with their web based employee task scheduling app. If you are looking for a hosted solution that is easy to use and manage all your work at single place [this system](http://www.eworksmanager.co.uk/staff-scheduling-software.html) is worth checking out.